# CoordinatorLayout Toolbar and Recyclerview inside fragment Cuts off bottom item

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

This is my layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</RecyclerView>
```

This happens if I use this in activity but using `setActionBar(toolbar)` fix this. But setting it in `Fragment` doesn't fix this. I cannot move the layout in activity because I'm using navigation graph. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I cant use `marginBottom` on `RecyclerView` because I will be reusing this setup on another `Fragment` but with a `Toolbar` of unknown height(`?attr/actionBarSize` + someheight)

Comment: Im not using any picture or gif.

Comment: try `clipToPadding = "false"` to recyclerview set `paddingBottom` and make recyclerview `height wrap_content`

Comment: @prashant17 that does work(same with margin_bottom) but the problem is I have to set its padding to the actual size of toolbar which I can't. because I have a toolbar with wrap_content. And it kinda feel hackish, the problem is the toolbar not taken into account by the recyclerview